# Java NotificationCompat Sound Not Ring

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am creating notification for my apps. I don't want to give a sound when the notification type is a progress bar.

```
// Run method 
progressNotification(context);

public void progressNotification(Context context){
    // Simulation download progress
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;
    while (min<=max){
        try{
            showNotification(context, true, min, max);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
        }
        min++;
    }
    // Send notification with sound
    showNotification(context, false, 0, 0);
}

public void showNotification(Context context, Boolean progress, int min, int max){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EntryActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    String notificationChannelId = createNotificationChannel(context, progress ? false : true);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannelId);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.message_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.message_content))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(context.getString(R.string.mask_message_content)))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    if(progress) {
        if(min<max) {
            mBuilder.setContentText("Downloading...").setProgress(max, min, false);
        }else{
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download Complete!").setProgress(0, 0,false);
        }
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(234, mBuilder.build());
}

private String createNotificationChannel(Context context, Boolean audio) {
    String channelId = "channelId";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "channel_name";
        String description = "channel_description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        // Here the condition
        if(!audio) channel.setSound(null, null);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        return channelId;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I set showNotification() with progress 'true' it means I disable sound, It works but when I show notificaiton again with progress 'false' it means I enable sound, but it is still disabled.

Comment: have you debugged your code ? maybe your boolean value is not being updated.

Comment: @Umair Yes I did, it is like there is a cache. If I reinstall my app and run the method to send standard notification (not progress) it works. But I have to reinstall first.

Comment: then it means the variable is not being updated. It's not the cache problem, please recheck your code.

Comment: @Umair I have debugged, I have tried to send notification 2 times. showNotification(this, true, 0, 0);
showNotification(this, false, 0, 0);
And I got boolean value of 'progress' is true and false

Comment: Then it should be working like this. If you are getting the values properly. Can you please implement it like I have in my answer and check if it works for you or not ?

Comment: Create a channel for the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I have to update or create an unique channelId each request NotificationChannel.

```
private String createNotificationChannel(Context context, Boolean audio) {

    String channelId = "channelId" + Boolean.toString(audio); // Here should be an unique id

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "channel_name";
        String description = "channel_description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        // Here the condition
        if(!audio) channel.setSound(null, null);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        return channelId;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way and I believe this will create a new notification based on the condition you are implementing:

```
               if (disableSound) {
                    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "")

                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                            .setSound(uri)
                            .setContentTitle("Expiry Date Reminder")
                            .setContentText("Your text")
                            .setAutoCancel(true) // clear notification after click
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                } else {
                    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "")
                            .setTicker(model.getProductName())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                            .setSound(uri)
                            .setContentTitle("Expiry Date Reminder")
                            .setContentText("Your text")
                            .setAutoCancel(true) // clear notification after click
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                }
```

Then the rest of your code will follow here:

```
 Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

 NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I have solved this problem, I have to update notification channel for new request notification. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your second notification sound is not working because you have created a notification channel with no sound. (To update the Notification Channel You need to Delete the Channel and then add again.)

```
// Here the condition
if(!audio) channel.setSound(null, null);
```

I will suggest to remove above line of code and make the following change in `NotificationCompat` class:

```
if(progress) {
    if(min<max) {
        mBuilder
             //Set priority to PRIORITY_LOW to mute notification sound
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW) 
            .setContentText("Downloading...").setProgress(max, min, false);
    }else{
        mBuilder
            .setContentText("Download Complete!").setProgress(0, 0,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved this problem, yes I have to update notification channel for new request notification. thanks

Comment: @AjieKurniyawan As per your answer, You have not updated Notification Channel but created two different notification channel.

Comment: Yes, it's just a trick to create an unique channel ID. I think every channel ID saves different settings. I just need two setting, enable and disable sound.